# Sort list of list erlang

Tags: erlang

```
PropertyInfo = [
    [{LandNo, Acquisition, Heir, Property, LandTypeCount, LandType}],
    [{LandNo, Acquisition, Heir, Property, LandTypeCount, LandType}],
    [{LandNo, Acquisition, Heir, Property, LandTypeCount, LandType}],
    [{LandNo, Acquisition, Heir, Property, LandTypeCount, LandType}],
]
```

`PropertyInfo` is a list of lists containing database objects in tuple, where `Heir:code()` will return a 6-digit code `eg. "010011", "00209", ""020011".`
How can I sort this list in erlang by using that Heir code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `lists:sort/2` and an ordering function:

[manual excerpt](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sort-2):

> sort(Fun, List1) -> List2
>
> Types:
>
> ```
> Fun = fun((A :: T, B :: T) -> boolean()) 
> List1 = List2 = [T] 
> T => term()
> ```
>
> Returns a list containing the sorted elements of List1,
>   according to the ordering function Fun. Fun(A, B) should return true
>   if A compares less than or equal to B in the ordering, false
>   otherwise.

Ordering fun could look like this:

```
fun([Tuple1],[Tuple2]) ->
    Prop1 = element(3,Tuple1);
    Prop2 = element(3,Tuple2); 
    case {Prop1:code(),Prop2:code()} of
        {Same,Same}   -> true;
        {Code1,Code2} -> SomeComparisonFun(Code1,Code2)
    end
    end
```

This leaves you to provide a function that can compare those values, once you've decided on a metric that let's you say which value should be greater than some other one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SortedList = lists:sort(
                         fun({_, _, A, _, _, _}, {_, _, B, _, _, _}) -> 
                              A:code() =< B:code() 
                         end, 
                         PropertyInfo).
```

This was very simple, I used this inbuilt `lists:sort()` function.